# Webkit translateY + textarea bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

Webkit only.
Lets imagine that we have a container with `translateY` css property.
This container contains textarea alement.
In this situalition textarea behavior is incorrect. When you try to enter more lines than textarea rows atribute has the autoscroll will not work until text height inside textarea will not be bigger than `textarea height` `+` `translateY * -1`.

[Please checkout example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/mT7Lp/)

Any ideas how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Is webkit bug, got to report Google so they can fix it. Try this see if it works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/mT7Lp/1/

Instead of using `translate`, use position `relative` and set top to -pixel

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use translateY to scroll container on mobile devices. And if I change it to absolute positioning it will slow down scrolling speed.
Probably I should add an option to switch between absolute positioning and translate on textarea focus/blur...